# Time Complexity Clarification On Backtracking Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I wrote the following algorithm to solve a classic backtracking question: write a program which takes an array of n integers, where A[i] denotes the maximum you can advance from index i, and returns whether it is possible to advance to the last index starting from the beginning of the array.

In other words, the ith entry in A is the max we can advance from i.

For example,
if A = [3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1], then the last index can be reached.
if A = [3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1], then it cannot.

I wrote the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
def array_advance(lst):
  dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
  return advance(0, lst, dict)

def advance(start_idx, lst, memo):
  if start_idx >= len(lst): return False 
  if start_idx == len(lst) -1: return True 
  step_size = lst[start_idx]
  for i in range(1, step_size + 1):
    memo[step_size] |= advance(start_idx + step_size, lst, memo)
    if memo[step_size]:
      return True 
  return False
```

With this code, I understand that there are just N function calls. If we memoize, each index is visited and the function(index) output is cached.

However, I'm having trouble understanding the time complexity. With regards to the size of the input, of course the time complexity scales with O(N). However, the contents of the input matter as well. If each element is, say, L, and the size of the input is 10L, the for loop will scale with O(L), running L times (one time from range(1, L + 1)), leading to O(L^2). If I'm answering an algorithm problem, or even trying to analyze time complexity, saying the time complexity O(N) because the time complexity scales with array length seems misleading, since it doesn't take into account the importance of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the step sizes never overshoot the array, you could say it's `O(sum(A))`, since that's a tight bound that takes into account the array elements. You could also say it's `O(N^2)`, since that's the worst case.

You can solve the problem in O(N) time and O(1) space by iterating through the array backwards, recording the least index found so far which allows you to get to the end.

```
def array_advance(a):
    i = len(a) - 1
    for j in range(i, -1, -1):
        if j + a[j] >= i: i = j
    return i == 0
```